# Unobtainable badges, should they shown in "unearned tab"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

If we go to the following page:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=unearned

We have badges that are not obtainable anymore like this:

- [Precognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/892/precognitive)
- [Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/30/beta)
- [Analytical](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1306/analytical)

If I look at "unearned" I expect I can catch them ;)

How do you think about it? Can we hide this?

Should not be so hard to implement. Thinking about a second column 'unobtainable' with `0` or `1` flag.

Comment: We need an Unobtanium badge.

Comment: @RobertHarvey this was a serious suggestion

Comment: @RobertHarvey is this an actual badge made of unobtanium? This would be quite tricky to manufacture: it always seems to be out of stock nowadays.

Comment: Marking as a duplicate of a newer question because that one has better answers and more discussion.